# Demo of an AngularJS directive's templateUrl in JsBin

Tags: angularjs-directive, jsbin

I have working code that I want to demo with JsBin but I can't get the AngularJS directive **templateUrl** to work (it does work with the **template** value).
http://jsbin.com/guvok/ is trying to reference http://jsbin.com/razit/ but fails.

For the sake of completeness and posterity here's the code:

#### hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hello">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div hello></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### hello.css

```
.hello__content {
    background: #fff;
  }
```

#### hello.js

```
var meter = angular.module('hello', [])
  .directive( 'hello', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      //template: '<p class="hello__content">hello</p>',
      templateUrl: 'http://jsbin.com/razit/',
    };
  });
```

#### template.html

```
<p>hello, world</p>
```

Comment: look at the error in the console, you might want to add the templates js to index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your HTML (after the script tag that loads Angular):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateURL">
  <!-- TEMPLATE MARKUP GOES HERE -->
</script>
```

Edit: In your case, the ID would be "http://jsbin.com/razit/", that way you wont have to edit your directive. Worst case, change the templateURL to not reference an external jsBin.

**Edit #2:** Changing the templateUrl to a string value **not** referencing an external url or with the http protocol, I now see your output in jsBin edit mode.

jsBin here: http://jsbin.com/dutofete/1/

Comment: Did you get any console output with this code in place?

Comment: Going to the url you just specified (not in edit mode) I can clearly see the 'hello, world' output. Is this not what you're expecting?

Comment: See my latest edit for a working example. More than likely, it has to do with cross referencing like GreyBeardedGeek pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

When I run http://jsbin.com/guvok/, I get the following error in the Javascript console in my browser:

```
Error: [$sce:insecurl] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$sce/insecurl?p0=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Frazit%2F
```

If you look up "$sce:insecurl", you'll find the [AngularJs error reference doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl) that says,

> AngularJS' Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) mode (enabled by default)
>   has blocked loading a resource from an insecure URL.
>
> Typically, this would occur if you're attempting to load an Angular
>   template from an untrusted source. It's also possible that a custom
>   directive threw this error for a similar reason.

It also offers a few ways to solve the problem, which is essentially a CORS issue.